# Problem with samba shares Ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, samba, file-server

I'm having a problem with setting up samba share permissions on Ubuntu Server LTS. I've got two shares set up in the `smb.conf` file. The entries look like this:

```
[share]
comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
path = "insert real path name here"
browsable = yes
guest ok = no
read only = no
create mask = 0700
group = group1

[media]
comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
path = "insert real path name here"
hide unreadable = yes
browsable = yes
guest ok = no
read only = no
group = group2
create mask = 0700
```

In the file system I am the owner of all directories related to both of these shares. The `[media]` share is group-owned by `group2`, and the `[share]` is group-owned by `group1`. For both directories I have file permissions set at 771, where owner and group both have read, write, and execute, but guests have only execute. I have 3 users in the system: myself, my wife, and my mother. I belong to `group1` and `group2`, as does my wife. My mother belongs only to `group2`. When I log into the server from my Windows desktop, my credentials work as expected. But if I use my wife's or my mother's, nothing works. They can log into the server, but when they click on one of the shared folders another log in screen is displayed asking for another username / password. This always fails and they are not allowed access to the folders.

I would like for my wife and I to have access to both of these folders while restricting access to other users. What am I missing here? I've tried fixing this for quite some time and I can't seem to get it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I had two problems:

- I didn't realize that a samba password needs to be assigned for each user
- The line `group = group1` needed to be changed to `write list = @group1`

Comment: There's no good way to answer an answer; if you have another question please [ask it separately](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions) (you can link to this one for background)

Answer (score 0):

First two places I check for samba-related (permission) errors are:-

```
/var/log/auth.log
/var/log/samba/*
```

Your `create mask` seems to only allow the owner to read, write and execute newly created files and folders. You probably want to add group read and execute permissions, by setting:

```
create mask = 0750
```

There is also the `directory mask` setting, which you would want to explicitly set to `0750` too.. The default is `0000`.

```
directory mask = 0750
```

Comment: @CraigSmith The execute flag on directories allows one to enter it, but to list a directory content, you need to have read permission.